# Is there a way to create reusable help documentation for commandlets

Tags: powershell

I have a custom PowerShell module with many cmdlets.  Several of the cmdlets take the same exact parameter.  I am using comment based help to document my cmdlets, e.g.:

```
<#
    .SYNOPSIS
        Does something

    .PARAMETER CommonParameter
        This documentation is copied and pasted across multiple cmdlets.
#>
```

The problem is that whenever I make a minor change to the documentation I have to track it down and change it everywhere.  Is there a way to create something a little more 'reusable'?  As in, I only update the documentation in one place and those changes are reflected everywhere.

Comment: AFAIK there is no documentation template engine for PowerShell.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not mind to use external help in generated XML files then take a look
at [Helps](https://github.com/nightroman/Helps). Its help scripts are in fact
PowerShell scripts, so you can define reusable pieces as variables and use them.

Here is the example of a help script: [Mdbc.dll-Help.ps1](https://github.com/nightroman/Mdbc/blob/master/Module/en-US/Mdbc.dll-Help.ps1).
This module has a lot of cmdlets with similar parameters. You can see that in
the beginning the scripts defines common help pieces as variables. They are
used later in several places.